# How can I call .WHY on a subroutine in a class in Perl 6?

Tags: metaprogramming, raku

Calling `.WHY` on something declared returns the special comments built around it. That's pretty cool. How can I refer to a subroutine defined in a class? Is it always hidden? I'm curious about modules that provide subroutines instead of classes (for which the answer might be "don't do it that way"). I'm mostly playing around with the limits of `.WHY` and how far I can take it.

```
#| This is the outside bit
sub outside { 137 }
put &outside.WHY; # This works

#| Class Foo is an example
class Foo {
    #| The bar method returns a number
    method bar { 137 }

    #| quux is a submethod
    submethod quux { 137 }

    #| qux is private
    submethod !qux { 137 }

    #| The baz method also returns a number
    sub baz { 37 }

    put &baz.WHY; # this works in this scope
    }

put "---- With an object";
quietly {
    my $object = Foo.new;
    put "As object: ", $object.WHY;

    # sub is not really a method?
    put "As object - bar: ", $object.^find_method( 'bar' ).WHY;

    # should this work? It *is* private after all
    put "As object - qux: ", $object.^find_method( 'qux' ).WHY;
    }

put "---- With class name";
quietly {
    put Foo.WHY;
    put "As class lookup: ", ::("Foo").WHY;
    put "As class lookup (quux): " ~  Foo.^lookup( 'quux' ).WHY;
    put "As class lookup (baz): " ~  Foo.^lookup( 'baz' ).WHY;  # nope!

    # this is the part where I need help
    put "As :: lookup: ", ::("Foo")::("&baz").WHY; #nope
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
This is the outside bit
The baz method also returns a number
---- With an object
As object: Class Foo is an example
As object - bar: The bar method returns a number
As object - qux:
---- With class name
Class Foo is an example
As class lookup: Class Foo is an example
As class lookup (quux): quux is a submethod
As class lookup (baz):
As :: lookup:
```

It's that last line of output I'm asking about. How can I get to a subroutine defined in a class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just lexical scoping at work:

Subs default to `my`, so if you want to get at them from the outside, you have to add an `our` (or expose them manually in some other fashion - as far as I'm aware, there's no builtin way to get at them, either through the MOP or other meta-programming capabilities like the `MY::` pseudo-package).

> I'm curious about modules that provide subroutines instead of classes

That's what `is export` is for.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
>     # should this work? It *is* private after all
>     put "As object - qux: ", $object.^find_method( 'qux' ).WHY;
> ```

Both of the following work:

```
put "As object - qux: ", $object.^find_private_method('qux').WHY;
put "As object - qux: ", $object.^private_method_table<qux>.WHY;
```

(`find_private_method` doesn't seem to be documented in p6doc, so I'm not sure if it is official API. [`private_method_table`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Metamodel$COLON$COLONPrivateMethodContainer#method_private_method_table) is documented, although not really explained.)

---

> ```
>     # this is the part where I need help
>     put "As :: lookup: ", ::("Foo")::("&baz").WHY; #nope
> ```

This one works if you declare `sub baz { 37 }` as `our sub baz { 37 }`.
You can also write the lookup more simply as:

```
put "As :: lookup: ", &Foo::baz.WHY;
```

The `our` declarator (explained in [Synopsis 3, section "Declarators"](http://design.perl6.org/S03.html#Declarators)) associates a symbol with the current package – in this case, a class – so that it can be accessed from outside of it using the `::` syntax.

By default, subroutines are lexically scoped – i.e. their default declarator, if none is specified, is `my`. (The statement `sub baz { 37 }` has basically<sup>1</sup> the same effect as writing `my &baz := sub { 37 }` at the top of the curly-brace-delimited scope.)
By writing `our sub baz { 37 }`, you're telling it to use `our` instead of `my` scoping.

---

> I'm curious about modules that provide subroutines instead of classes

Either declare it with `our` as shown above *(in which case the user scope will have to use the fully qualified name `Foo::baz`)*, or export it into the user scope *(in which case they can refer to it as just `baz`)*.

The easiest way to make a symbol exportable, is to use the `is export` trait:

```
module Foo {
    #| The baz method also returns a number
    sub baz is export(:ALL) { 37 }
}

import Foo :ALL;

say &baz.WHY;
```

A `use` statement implicitly calls `import` on the module in question. Since here the module is defined in the same file, we can just call import directly.

Note that you can also write `sub baz is export { 37 }` (without the `:ALL`), in which case the symbol would be imported by default whenever the class is `use`'d or `import`'ed. But in the Perl 5 / CPAN community that's considered bad practice, and letting users import individual symbols is recommended. In Perl 6, importing individual symbols doesn't work yet, so I recommend using the `:ALL` tag for now.

---

<sup>1) The only difference I'm aware of, is that in the first case the routine knows its own name for introspection purposes.</sup>